# Why does Scala's require method in Predef allow a String as argument?

Tags: scala

I can the require method in Scala's Predef class with a String as second argument, e.g.

```
require ("foo" == "bar", "foobar")
```

First a thought the require method is overloaded for different parameters as second argument. But it is not. The Signature of the require method (Scala 2.9.1) is:

```
require(requirement: Boolean, message: ⇒ Any): Unit
```

Why is the above method call possible ?

Comment: What's wrong with the definition?
`"foo" == "bar"` is a `Boolean` value and a `String` conforms to `Any` (as _any_ type does).

Comment: The question is, why a String is valid type for the second argument while the signatures says it has to be a function 'message: => Any'

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't fully understand the question, but here is a bit of explanation. `require` has one overloaded version in `Predef`:

```
def require(requirement: Boolean) //...
def require(requirement: Boolean, message: => Any) //...
```

The second one is a bit confusing due to `message: => Any` type. It would probably be easier if it was simply:

```
def require(requirement: Boolean, message: Any) //...
```

The second parameter is of course a message that is suppose to be appended to error message if assertions is not met. You could imagine `message` should be of `String` type but with `Any` you can simply write:

```
require(x == 4, x)
```

Which will add actual value of `x` (of type `Int`) into an error message if it is not equal to `4`. That's why `Any` was chosen - to allow arbitrary value.

But what about `: =>` part? This is called *call by name* and basically means: evaluate this parameter *when it is accessed*. Imagine the following snippet:

```
require(list.isEmpty, list.size)
```

In this case you want to be sure the `list` is empty - and if it is not, add the actual `list` size to the error message. However with normal call convention the `list.size` part must be evaluated *before* the method is called - which might be wasteful. With *call by name* convention the `list.size` is only evaluated the first time it is used - when the error message is constructor (if required).

Comment: @Tomasz - I am going to edit the answer to remove the word "lazily" from the description of call-by-name. I think this is misleading. There's a distinct difference between lazy (evaluate once) and call-by-name (evaluate each access).

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: no problem, I understand it can be confused with `lazy` keyword. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `require` method existed in `Predef` before scala had default parameters (introduced in 2.8), so overloading was the only option if you wanted default behaviour for a given parameter. As indicated by the message, the second argument may be anything, which is then used as the `message` (by calling its `toString` method) of the thrown `IllegalArgumentException`, (*if* it is thrown - i.e. *if the requirement fails*).

Notice that the argument is, in fact, a **call by name**; that is, it is declared as `=> Any`, which means it will **only be evaluated if the requirement fails**.

This inflicts a performance penalty in the form of an object creation, but it may be useful in the case where the construction of your message is expensive (perhaps it requires some O(n) access to a data-structure).

Answer (score 2):

> The question is, why a String is valid type for the second argument
>   while the signatures says it has to be a function `message: => Any`.

The signature doesn't say that. The signature says the second argument is *of type `Any`*, and that this parameter is *passed by name*.

The "by name" is indicated by the prefixing `=>` symbol which does *not* mean function -- a function is always indicated as *input parameters* => *result type*, with `Function0` being `() => type`.

Look up parameters "by value" and "by name".

Answer (score -1):

The answer is quite simple: You expect the second argument of

```
require(boolean: Boolean, message: => Any): Unit
```

to be a *Function* to *Any* and ask why a `String` works, even though it is not a *Function*.

Break it down to this: A fixed `String` is nothing but a *Function* that

1. does not take any arguments
2. does not require the `()` parenthesis to be called
3. yields the same result in every call

In fact the following two statements are equivalent in Scala:

```
def x: String = "ABC" // const value, even though 'def' implies a function
val x: String = "ABC"
```

So you might say the `=> Any` is satisfied by a `String`.